# Why don't my changes to devise views appear in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have generated a Devise User where the layout is different of the layout of application.html.erb, so I modify the application_controller.rb for this:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    layout :layout_by_resource

  private

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "devise"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

So I created the layout "devise.html.erb" in views/layouts with the follow code:

```
<%=render "layouts/site/navbar"%>
    
    <%= yield %>
```

after i generated the views of devise with command "rails g devise:views user", this views stay in views/users, but the alterations of layouts I make doesnt work.

Comment: look at [this](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-views)

Comment: Thanks, had forgotten about config.scoped_views = true on devise.rb.